# Mongodb query or ETL tool

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, etl

I am working on project where real time data is stored in Mongo DB. I need to analyze that data and calculate new parameters using present one in database.
Analysis may vary from basic statistics to predicting value from previous one 
I came across with two approaches that is Mongo dB queries using pymongo or ETL tool. 
Please help me to find the best approach for this.

Comment: What are the basic statistics that you are looking for?

Comment: Basic statistics includes average, sum, count.

Comment: If it is basic like average, sum, and count then try using Map Reduce in MongoDB